# Visual Studio Makefile Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, templates, wizard, project-template

I have a custom compiler for my projects, and I really like Visual Studio as a development environment.  So, for my projects, I create a Makefile project and make it use my custom compiler. However, the setup for this is very time consuming, and I do it a lot.

So, I want to create a project template for this Makefile project.  But, in Visual Studio (2010), the "Export Template..." feature doesn't work for C++ projects.  I'm starting to experiment with making a Custom Wizard project for C++.

My question is how do I create a Custom Wizard project which creates a Makefile project?  I would like this integrated into the New Project menu in Visual Studio.

Thanks.